# ./gradlew assemble fails due to missing file when the file clearly exists

Tags: java, windows, shell, gradle, command-line

I'm trying to [build JPostal as described in this link](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal#building-jpostal) using the following command:

```
./gradlew assemble
```

However, the command produces the following output claiming the file `C:\x\Program Files\Msys64\usr\share` does not exist **when it clearly does**:

```
$ ./gradlew assemble

:buildJniLibaclocal-1.16: error: aclocal: file '/x/Program Files/Msys64/usr/share/aclocal/tcl-tea.m4' does not exist
autoreconf-2.71: error: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: Files/JPostal/src/main/jniLibs
configure: error: cannot find required auxiliary files: compile config.guess config.sub ltmain.sh missing install-sh
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildJniLib'.
> Process 'command 'sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.844 secs
```

I can clearly see a file named `tcl-tea.m4` in the directory: `C:\x\Program Files\Msys64\usr\share\aclocal`

See the **screenshot** below:

[image]

If the file clearly exists, why am I getting this error? Why is the file being discriminated against?

Comment: What is the directory the gradle project is located under? Is it in `C:`?

Comment: @dan1st Thanks for your reply. `JPostal` (which is the project I'm trying to build) is located under the directory: `C:\x\Program Files\JPostal` (`x` is being used as a placeholder for a custom folder name). The actual `.gradle` installation is under: `C:\Users\xyz\.gradle`

Comment: Maybe try building it in a folder without spaces.

Comment: @dan1st Thanks for your suggestion. As per your suggestion, I tried changing `Program Files` to `ProgramFiles` (removed the space) but I still get the same error.

Comment: The link you posted is a link to the screenshot. Is there a link to the directions you are following that was meant to be that link?

Comment: @FranciscoMateo Oops, my mistake. I intended to post the link to the directions. I'm updating the post [with the correct link](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal#building-jpostal).

Comment: For information purposes, I had previously ran into [the issue raised here](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal/issues/37) and solved it by changing `commandLine ./build.sh` to `commandLine sh./build.sh` [as suggested in above thread](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal/issues/37#issuecomment-572235426) - not sure if this matters but thought I'll share just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite these are supported, but paths with spaces generally tend to be problematic on Linux.
Even without the `build.gradle`, the path is obviously wrong; this likely needs to be escaped:

```
"C:\\x\\Program\ Files\\Msys64\\usr\\share\\aclocal"
```

Where `\\` gives `\` and `\`  gives  .

---

To use `${File.separator}` would be the alternate cross-platform approach.

This would give `\` on Windows and `/` on Linux.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I don't see any file that contains the path: `"C:\\x\\Program\ Files\\Msys64\\usr\\share\\aclocal"`? If you mean when typing path in the `MSYS2` editor I always escape any path that contains a space. BTW, I am using Windows. Can you please clarify where I should escape this path? The file `build.gradle` does not explicitly contain any path with space. I had also temporarily changed the directory `Program Files` to `ProgramFile` (removed the space) - and executed the command again but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs This question features no `build.gradle` and that path has to come from somewhere. I can well see by the path that you're probably building with `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` ...which might count as external native build. It's either the `build.gradle` or `Makefile`, which `gcc` uses. A path alike `C:\\Home\\Msys64` might generally be less problematic.

Comment: https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal/issues/40 ...the provided build environment is probably "not sane", when running `gcc` below a path with spaces. And the whole repository does not mention Msys64 at all... building on WSL2 would not depend on that.